# Is there a way to test Azure CosmosDb locally with a Linux docker image?

Tags: mongodb, azure, docker, azure-cosmosdb

Unfortunately Microsoft's docker image is Windows only which isn't suitable in our case: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator/

I was wondering if we'd be able to use a MongoDb docker image to test locally, would that work? Are the APIs compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB is compatible with [server version 3.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36) so possibly yes.

If you don't have to test locally there are free options for testing including [free tier](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/build-apps-for-free-with-azure-cosmos-db-free-tier/) which gives you 400 RU/s and 5GB free for ever. Or you can use [Try Cosmos](https://azure.microsoft.com/try/cosmosdb/) which gives you 30 days free at higher RU/s.

Hope that is helpful.